# Mount directly over /mnt by mistake

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ext4

I have performed a rsync between two folders:

```
rsync -avzh /mnt/folder1 /mnt/folder2
```

(folder1 was /dev/sdb and folder2 was /dev/sdc, both ext4 partitions)

Then I have unmounted folder1 and I made a mistake and I mounted /dev/sdc directly over /mnt with:

```
mount /dev/sdc /mnt
```

When in fact I wanted to mount /dev/sdc over /mnt/folder1

Now I am not able to umount /mnt:

```
umount /mnt/
umount: /mnt/: target is busy
    (In some cases useful info about processes that
     use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, to **prevent data loss** !

Run the following command, to see what process prevents unmounting. I am assumimg, that you skipped the partition on the dev to type less:

```
lsof | grep '/dev/sdc'
```

Close your work or end the given processes and unmount again. You cal also see, what files are still open with:

```
fuser -u /mnt/
```

Whereas the following command will kill all processes itself and probaply result in data loss:

```
fuser -km /mnt
```

Or show it as unmounted and let it automatically unmount, when the processes have finished:

```
umount -l /mnt
```

Answer (score 1):

Check so that there isn't any process using the mountpoint, like your own shell for example.

If that doesn't do it

```
lsof |grep /mnt/
```

can help you pinpoint what's using the mountpoint.